# Creating a table displaying percentages of a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a table of user data that includes the state the user is from and a unique ID:

### mytable

| state | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| Colorado | 1 |
| Florida | 2 |
| Colorado | 3 |
| Utah | 4 |
| New York | 5 |
| Maine | 6 |

What I'm trying to get out of this is a new table that shows the percent of users from certain states; specifically Colorado, Florida, and Other, and have these be the columns in the new table:

| Colorado | Florida | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33.3% | 16.7% | 50% |

Here's my current code:

```
select
    case
        when state = 'Colorado'
        then concat(round(count(user_id)*100.0/6,1), '%') 
    end "Colorado",
    case
        when state = 'Florida'
        then concat(round(count(user_id)*100.0/6,1), '%') 
    end "Florida",
    case
        when state not in ('Colorado', 'Florida')
        then concat(round(count(user_id)*100.0/6,1), '%') 
    end "Other"
from mytable
group by state
```

[This is the output]

[image: 1]

So it looks like it's creating a row for each state in the table and putting the percent in that row. I'm looking for advice on how to get it to the example I posted above. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: can you put a distinct on your query ? like `select distinct * from (your query) q;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest conditional aggregation:

```
select avg( (state = 'Colorado')::int ) as ratio_co,
       avg( (state = 'Florida')::int ) as ratio_fl,
       avg( (state not in ('Colorado', 'Florida'))::int ) as ratio_other
from mytable;
```

This produces the ratio as a number between 0 and 1.  You can multiply by 100 and format the results if you really want.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you! Wasn't familiar with conditional aggregation, but this actually makes a lot of sense. Did a bit of formatting and was able to get exactly what I was looking for, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to percentage calculation:

```
SELECT state, round(count(*)::decimal / (select count(*) from t) * 100, 2) AS per
FROM t 
GROUP BY state;
```

To transpose de table you could use crosstab() function, but i think this static pivot won't be useful in this case.

This query is a kind of dynamic pivot but I don't know if will be useful for you:

```
SELECT array_agg(state || ': ' || per || ' %') AS data
FROM (
   SELECT state, round(count(*)::decimal / (select count(*) from t) * 100, 2) AS per
   FROM t 
   GROUP BY state) AS aux;
```

Output (with my example data):

| Data |
| --- |
| {"New York: 25.00","Colorado: 25.00","Florida: 50.00"} |